# What are the differences between creating signals in these two different ways?

Tags: python, pyside2

Using PySide2, it's possible to create signals in two ways that I know of:

```py
file_changed = Signal()
```

or

```py
@Signal
def file_changed(self):
    pass
```

They both seem to do the same thing.  What if I want a signal that can `emit` a value?  I know I can do:

```py
file_changed = Signal(str)

...

def load_file(self, file_name):
   self.file_changed.emit(file_name)
```

But what is the equivalent using the `@Signal` decorator?

Comment: My question is: why do you want to use that strange way? You could also indicate the docs where that second form is indicated.

Comment: If decorator support was added by design it's hard to see why anyone would want to use it. Maybe it's just a wart (i.e. an inintentional "feature").

Comment: Here is an example reference to the @Signal decorator from Qt's website: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_UsingQtProperties

Comment: That example still looks like a wart. Does PySide2 somehow require QML property notifier signals to be declared in that way? Why can't a normal signal declaration be used?

Comment: I'm not sure.  What's what I'm asking.  Is there a preference. I'd like to understand why and what role the two different ways to implement signals are.

Comment: @roundtheworld The NOTIFYable properties only need a signal without arguments so it works. I agree with what ekhumoro points out. For me (since I do not see anything documented) the second method has no advantage, but it does have a disadvantage: it does not allow to indicate arguments in the creation of signals, so IMHO uses the first method.

Comment: @roundtheworld I would say the preference is to avoid using poorly documented APIs that have no obvious rationale. The existing signal declaration syntax is well documented and also matches what is found in PyQt. I don't see any useful role for the decorator syntax.